# How to store specific data from web request response?

Tags: python, http-headers, request-headers

I am executing this script which makes a web request:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import requests
import sched, time
import json

from pprint import pprint

cookies = {'_globalinstancekey': '1594227/1/7JtxqlA7M68O42U73B_MWA=='}

def main():
    url = "http://transparency.hackxor.net/blog"

    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

    print "\nRequest: \n";
    print vars(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

`{'cookies': <RequestsCookieJar[]>, '_content': '<!DOCTYPE
html>\n<html>\n... comment from Black: removed, because irrelevant for
this post ...\n</html>', 'headers': {'X-Cache': 'HIT',
'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Age':
'56', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control':
'public; max-age: 60;', 'Date': 'Sat, 05 Oct 2019 19:23:34 GMT',
'Content-Type': 'text/html'}, 'url':
u'http://transparency.hackxor.net/blog', 'status_code': 200,
'_content_consumed': True, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1', 'request':
<PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'connection': <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter
object at 0x7f00a2bd7b90>, 'elapsed': datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 74170),
'raw': <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f00a2c006d0>,
'reason': 'OK', '_next': None, 'history': []}`

I tried to save some values from the output into variables, e.g. the value of `X-Cache` and `Age`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X-Cache` and `Age` are under headers. To get this information, do:

```
>>> print r.headers['X-Cache']
HIT
>>> print r.headers['Age']
48
```